# Foreach Loop Of Post Types With Nested If Else If Not Completing Process

Tags: php, wordpress, for-loop, if-statement

When my plugin is updated I am trying to write new values to the database. I am running through the post types and if it is Page Product or Post I want to place INDEX in to the DB. Else I want to place NO-INDEX into the DB. The INDEX part loops properly, or at least the best I can tell as the values are stored in the DB. But when it gets to the NO-INDEX, it processes the first post type, which is ATTACHMENTS, and then does not get or process the remaining post types. I have tried several variations on the code and cannot seem to get it to work correctly. What am I doing wrong here?

I am using add_option and register_setting

Here is the code:

```
function set_activation_value(){
    // Sets Field Defaults
    $option = get_option('ews_index_option_name');
    if (empty($option)) {
        $args = array (
            'public' => true
        ); 
        $post_types = get_post_types( $args, 'names' ); 
        $my_options = get_option('ews_index_option_name');
        $post_type_output = '';
        foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) {
            if (($post_type == "page") || ($post_type == "product") || ($post_type == "post")) {
                $my_options = get_option('ews_index_option_name');
                $my_options["$post_type"] = 'index';
                update_option('ews_index_option_name', $my_options);
            }
            else if (($post_type != "page") && ($post_type != "product") && ($post_type != "post")) {
                $my_options = get_option('ews_index_option_name');
                $my_options["$post_type"] = 'no-index';
                update_option('ews_index_option_name', $my_options);
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();
            $post_type_output .= $post_type;
        }
        update_option('ews_index_my_types', $post_types);
        update_option('ews_index_option_var', $post_type_output);
    }
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'set_activation_value' );
```

When I run the update I get the following results:

posts='**index**' pages='**index**' attachments='**no-index**' wpm-testimonials='' rl-galleries=''

What I expect to get is:

posts='**index**' pages='**index**' attachments='**no-index**' wpm-testimonials='**no-index**' rl-galleries='**no-index**'

The database also shows the same data as what these pictures represent. I have also added other post types to check and on the else or if else it never gets past the attachments.

I have also tried the following code with no success:

```
foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) {
    if (($post_type == "page") || ($post_type == "product") || ($post_type == "post")) {
        $my_options = get_option('ews_index_option_name');
        $my_options["$post_type"] = 'index';
        update_option('ews_index_option_name', $my_options);
    } else {
        $my_options = get_option('ews_index_option_name');
        $my_options["$post_type"] = 'no-index';
        update_option('ews_index_option_name', $my_options);
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, been at this for a while. I am not terribly good with loops and arrays, which may be apparent here. Thank you!

Comment: here `$my_options["$post_type"]` doublequotes not required

Comment: why `"product"` isn't present in the result list?

Comment: try `var_dump($post_types)` after `$post_types = get_post_types( $args, 'names' );`

Comment: OK, remove the quotes form the []. Product is only not displaying because WooCommerce currently isn't installed. Sorry for the confusion there.

Comment: I'll try the vardump now. BTW, I did remove the public $args and name and the loop is getting all of the other items and no indexing them but still not grabbing the other plugins' post types.

Comment: perhaps not all of them meet default parameters of `get_post_types()`

Comment: When it is called elsewhere in the plugin, they do pull through though using, seemingly, the same code:

Comment: `<div class="indexing-wrapper-inner">
        <?php settings_fields( 'ews_index_option_group' ); ?>
        <?php
  $args = array (
   'public' => true,
  ); 
  $post_types = get_post_types( $args, 'names' ); 
  $this_post_type = get_option('ews_index_option_name');         
  foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) {
   ?>
   <div class="post-type-container">
    <div class="post-type-heading">
     <h2><?php echo $post_type .'s'; ?></h2>
    </div>`

Comment: `<div class="post-type-options">
     <label>Yes</label>
     <input type="radio" name="ews_index_option_name[<?php echo $post_type; ?>]" value="index" <?php checked( 'index' == $this_post_type[''.$post_type.''] ); ?> />
     <label>No</label>
     <input type="radio" name="ews_index_option_name[<?php echo $post_type; ?>]" value="no-index" <?php checked( 'no-index' == $this_post_type[''.$post_type.''] ); ?> />
    </div>
   </div>
   <?php
   wp_reset_postdata();
  } ?>
        </div>`

Comment: Sorry that formatting is terrible. Not sure how else to share it with you.

Comment: However the other use of this is on an admin page(which is working fine) and not being output to the wp_head(which is not working fine)

Comment: VAR DUMP RESULTS= array(3) {
  ["post"]=>
  string(4) "post"
  ["page"]=>
  string(4) "page"
  ["attachment"]=>
  string(10) "attachment"
}
Is it possibly due to where or how this is being called that it won't grab the post types created by other plugins?

Comment: I think here the answer: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-post-type-not-showing-in-get_post_types-array/

Comment: Here are the two spots where the function is called. When I do an update from the plugins page, that is what I am trying to troubleshoot.`// Current version number
if (!defined('EWS_METAS_VERSION'))
define('EWS_METAS_VERSION', '1.1.6');

function myplugin_check_version() {
if (EWS_METAS_VERSION !== get_option('ews_metas_version'))
set_activation_value();
}
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'myplugin_check_version');

function update_meta_function() {
set_activation_value();
}
add_action( 'upgrader_process_complete', 'update_meta_function' );`

Comment: This may play into the challenges, like you had referenced in the timing issue from that other post.

Answer (score 0):

Code below has to give the same result as yours, but it's a bit shorter. Less code - less errors.

```
function set_activation_value(){
    // Sets Field Defaults
    $my_options = get_option('ews_index_option_name');
    if ( empty( $my_options ) ) {
        $args = array ( 'public' => true ); 
        $post_types = get_post_types( $args, 'names' ); 
        $post_type_output = implode('', $post_types);

        foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) {
            $my_options[ $post_type ] = ( in_array( $post_type, ["page", "product", "post"] ) ) ? 'index' : 'no-index';
        }
        update_option('ews_index_option_name', $my_options);
        update_option('ews_index_my_types', $post_types);
        update_option('ews_index_option_var', $post_type_output);
    }
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'set_activation_value' );
```

Comment: That indeed does still work the same as my above code and is much simpler. Thank you.